# How to access java field values from another class?

Tags: java

I guess the errors mentioned below belongs to something about the scope of variables while accessing them in another class. I would appreciate your help resolving this.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new CurrencyConversionFrame();
  } 
}
```

```
public class CurrencyConversionFrame extends JFrame {
  private JTextField currencyAmountField;

  private JButton createConvertButton() {
    JButton button = new JButton("Convert");
    ActionListener listener = new ConvertListener();
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    return button;
  }
}
```

```
class ConvertListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
    double balance = 0;
    try {
      balance = Double.parseDouble(currencyAmountField.getText());
    }
  }
}
```

The code provided above contains snippets from the original lengthy code. I have three classes "ConvertListener", "CurrencyConversionFrame" and one main class "Main". When I run the code I only get the following errors for all the variables declared in "CurrencyConversionFrame" class.

```
ConvertListener.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
      balance = Double.parseDouble(currencyAmountField.getText());
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable currencyAmountField
  location: class ConvertListener
```

Comment: currencyAmoundField is private - you can not access it from outside the class. You have at least two possibilities: (1) make it public (with all known setbacks) (2) implement a getter-function into the class

Answer (score 1):

In order to access a class fields (conventionally) you should declare getters and setters so in your case it would be

```
public void setCurrencyAmountField(JTextField currencyAmountField) {
    this.currencyAmountField = currencyAmountField;
}

public JTextField getCurrencyAmountField() {
    return this.currencyAmountField;
}
```

This way accessing the variable is doable through the getCurrencyAmountField();

Also one thing that might help is to implement the ActionListener directly into the frame and determine through a switch statement what type of action was actually performed (if the frame has more than one possibility)

```
public class CurrencyConversionFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   
   ...
   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        switch(action.getActionCommand()) {
            case "Name Of the button":
                balance = Double.parseDouble(currencyAmountField.getText());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("The action is not yet defined");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event source items is accessed through the `ActionEvent#getSource` method and you should not need to access the origin field:

```
class ConvertListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
    double balance = 0;
    try {
      Object source = action.getSource(); // here you have the source button and you can deal with its content
    }
  }
}
```

When dealing with UI component generally in Swing / JavaFX world, event listeners are encapsulated within their dependent component (since they are generally tied to the latter), hence they get access to the `outer` type fields.

If you then still need to access the underlying field directly, *which is discouraged*, you can then move your `ConvertListener` to be an inner type or your UI component.